# How to achieve animated handwriting with variable thickness?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, text-object

There's a nice tutorial here showing how to get such an effect by tracing a real text object and creating a cruve from it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUVUR9jupMY

The problem is this makes all the text lines be the same thickness which is unnatural for handwriting.
There's a trick mentioned in the tutorial which is having a plane behind the text curve and moving the sections of the curve you don't want to see behind the plane which could also be used to make same section of the curve less thick but that would take very long to prepare. Is there a less time consuming way to do it?

Comment: We managed to create a script which parses several fonts and recreates the exact thickness of each letter.
You may take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvL-ZqG5aVo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control the thickness of a curve's bevel by changing the radius of a particular segment:

[image]

To get something like this:

[image]

Examlple file:

[image]

Be aware that the tools to create and manipulate curves in blender are not as responsive and sofisticated as other programs out there, so to create complex curves like this, it might be easier to work in Inkscape, Illustrator or other vector graphics program and export the file in SGV format and import it into blender.

Comment: is there a way to have the beginning and end "filled" (not flat if the radius is not 0 which makes it sharp)

Comment: @LeoErvin they can be whatever radius you set them to be.

Comment: It's not about radius. By default the tip is flat. You can make it sharp by settign radius to 0, but no way I see of making the tip circular (smooth)