# Font that looks as if made out of ribbons?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Can I use blender to create and render something like the text in the image below? If I were to make my name, using this type of ribbon "font". How can I create these letters?

[image: reference image of the text]

Comment: If you see an answer that works for you, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a curve object that uses a second curve as a bevel object, and you can rotate the control points with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and move them in 3d space.

[image]

Comment: You can even make the text write itself on the screen by setting keyframes for the path animation start and end See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/how-to-achieve-animated-handwriting-with-variable-thickness/48130#48130

Comment: Note that this can also be done without a bevel object and just extruding the curve.

Comment: Bevel object allows to bend the ribbon inward to itself, straight extrusion doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array along a curve. This way you can easily rotate your ribbon. Like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUc-mEdzZ48)

A perhaps more intuitive Alternative would be to just model a long stretched plain and add  the solidify and subsurface modifiers. Like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNhdgYic9js)