# Blender how to scale individual vertices on a curve?

Tags: edit-mode, path, bevel

I set a bevel on a curve, but supposedly there is a way to scale vertices of a curve so that they also scale the radius of the corresponding bevel. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: If this is what you mean ... in edit mode, you can scale the radius around selected vertices using Alt-S, (Shrink/Fatten)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/how-to-achieve-animated-handwriting-with-variable-thickness/48130#48130 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594