# How can you Path Extrude over time?

Tags: animation, extrude, path

I want to extrude along a path over time so as to animate a path growing over time. How can I do that in Blender?

Comment: You can animate the bevel start and end of a curve read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/34383#34383 and maybe : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/how-to-achieve-animated-handwriting-with-variable-thickness/48130#48130

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/